# How can I remove a lot of items through commands when they give me immense lag when I near them?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Is there a command I can use? If so please let me know what it is.

I have tried the following:

```
/kill @e[type=minecraft:item,nbt={Item:{id:"minecraft:dirt"}}]
```

Comment: Your command seems correct. It’s probably something about your setup instead.

Comment: I think you self-answered. Does it work?

Comment: Make sure the affected chunks are loaded when you run the command.

Answer (score -1):

You would use something like this:
`/kill @e[type=item, distance=..15]`
This will kill all items within 15 blocks of you thus removing lag.